# Overloading operator +: Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I'm working on some code that uses linked lists, and I'm having a hard time determining why my + operator is not working, I keep getting the above error.

What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct sortedListNode
{
    char letter;
    int occurrences = 1;
    sortedListNode *next;
};

sortedListNode *operator+(sortedListNode *lhs, sortedListNode *rhs)
{

    int i = 0;
    sortedListNode *head, *tail, *curr, *prev, *tempLoc;
    sortedListNode *list1, *list1curr, *list2, *list2curr;
    list1 = lhs;
    list2 = rhs;

    // Copy list1 into output list

    head = new sortedListNode;
    head->letter = list1->letter;
    head->occurrences = list1->occurrences;
    head->next = NULL;
    tail = head;

    list1curr = list1;
    list1curr = list1curr->next;

    while (list1curr != NULL)
    {
        tempLoc = new sortedListNode;
        tempLoc->letter = list1curr->letter;
        tempLoc->occurrences = list1curr->occurrences;
        tempLoc->next = NULL;

        tail->next = tempLoc;
        tail = tempLoc;

        list1curr = list1curr->next;
    }

    curr = head;
    while (list2curr != NULL)
    {

        while (curr != NULL)
        {

            if (curr->letter == list2curr->letter)
            {
                curr->occurrences++;
                break;
            }
            else if ((curr->letter > list2curr->letter) && (curr == head))
            {
                tempLoc = new sortedListNode;
                tempLoc->next = curr;
                tempLoc->letter = list2curr->letter;
                head = tempLoc;
                break;
            }
            else if ((curr->letter > list2curr->letter) && (curr != head))
            {
                tempLoc = new sortedListNode;
                tempLoc->next = curr;
                tempLoc->letter = list2curr->letter;
                prev->next = tempLoc;
                break;
            }
            else if ((curr == tail) && (curr->letter < list2curr->letter))
            {
                tempLoc = new sortedListNode;
                tempLoc->next = NULL;
                tempLoc->letter = list2curr->letter;
                tail->next = tempLoc;
                tail = tempLoc;
                break;
            }

            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;

        }

        curr = head;
        list2curr = list2curr->next;
    }


    return head;


}

sortedListNode *fromString(string inWord)
{

    int i = 0;
    sortedListNode *head, *tail, *curr, *prev, *tempLoc;

    // Put the first letter in as the first element, set head and
    // tail to this element.
    head = new sortedListNode;
    tail = head;

    head->letter = inWord[0];
    head->next = NULL;

    curr = head;
    for (int i = 1; inWord[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        while (curr != NULL)
        {

            if (curr->letter == inWord[i])
            {
                curr->occurrences++;
                break;
            }
            else if ((curr->letter > inWord[i]) && (curr == head))
            {
                tempLoc = new sortedListNode;
                tempLoc->next = curr;
                tempLoc->letter = inWord[i];
                head = tempLoc;
                break;
            }
            else if ((curr->letter > inWord[i]) && (curr != head))
            {
                tempLoc = new sortedListNode;
                tempLoc->next = curr;
                tempLoc->letter = inWord[i];
                prev->next = tempLoc;
                break;
            }
            else if ((curr == tail) && (curr->letter < inWord[i]))
            {
                tempLoc = new sortedListNode;
                tempLoc->next = NULL;
                tempLoc->letter = inWord[i];
                tail->next = tempLoc;
                tail = tempLoc;
                break;
            }

            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;

        }

        curr = head;

    }

    return head;
}

void printList(sortedListNode *inSortedListNode)
{
    sortedListNode *curr;
    curr = inSortedListNode;
    int nodeCounter = 0;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        nodeCounter++;
        cout << "Node " << nodeCounter << " at " << curr << " - Letter = " << curr->letter << ", Occurrences = " << curr->occurrences << ", Next Node = "
            << curr->next << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }


}

int main()
{

    string word1, word2;

    sortedListNode *list1;
    sortedListNode *list2;
    sortedListNode *list3;

    cout << "Enter first word: ";
    cin >> word1;
    cout << "Enter second word: ";
    cin >> word2;

    list1 = fromString(word1);
    cout << "Letter list from word one: " << endl;
    printList(list1);

    list2 = fromString(word2);
    cout << "Letter list from word two: " << endl;
    printList(list2);

    list3 = list1 + list2;
    cout << "Letter list from both words: " << endl;
    printList(list3);


    cin.ignore(32767, '\n');

    char dummy[1]{};

    cin.getline(dummy, 1);



}
```

Please note I am aware that there are errors in the operator definition as I've not finished writing that yet.  I'm trying to get past the hurdle of taking two linked list sortedListNode objects as parameters.

This is for an assignment.  The main is a stub main that has been provided by the instructor.  The operator + is supposed to take two lists and merge them together, and output the merged list.

Comment: I'm having a hard time determining what code you are trying to compile . Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Clarified that the operator call is within the main and that's where I'm getting the syntax error.

Comment: Shall the `+` operator just concatinate the two lists (i.e. link them together) or return a new list that equals the concatination of the input lists? Your code seems to do the latter, but then the arguments (`lhs`, `rhs`) could be `const sortedListNode*`.

Comment: Sorry, it should return a new list, that's correct.

Comment: are you allowed to use functions from the `std` namespace?

Comment: Only string and cin/cout type functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error message is that the `operator+` that you have defined is not being called. That's because you have defined your `operator+` to take two `sortedListNode`s as parameters, but you have passed in two pointers instead. if you change your operator to take pointers instead (`sortedListNode*`), it will get past the immediate syntax error.

However, that's where your real problems begin. Your implementation of operator+ is also faulty. It returns `head`which is not a part of the `sortedListNode`  structure. Crucially, it does not make any use of either of the two lists that you pass in to it.

Edit: now we can see the full code, thanks for posting that.

I would echo what Walter said: adding pointers makes no sense. Instead you should define an operator+ for adding lists together:

```
sortedNodeList operator+(const sortedNodeList& lhs, const sortedNodeList &rhs){
  ...
}
```

In other words, your arguments should be references to lists (not pointers) and your result should be a list, not a pointer.

Comment: Head is a pointer to the first node of a *sortedListNode.  Perhaps it would be more useful if I post all my code, I will do so.

Comment: Updated with full code.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it this way.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
sortedListNode *list1, *list2, *list3;
list3 = list1 + list2;
```

you need

```
sortedListNode *operator+(sortedListNode*lhs, sortedListNode*rhs);
```

but you only provide

```
sortedListNode *operator+(sortedListNode lhs, sortedListNode rhs);
```

---

I should also say that overloading the `+` operator for pointer types makes no sense (even if it was allowed).

Comment: Thanks @Walter.  The fun part about that is if I do that, I then get a syntax error on the operator definition itself, stating: "Nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type."  I essentially want it to take as input two pointers to sortedListNode s and return one pointer to a sortedListNode.

Comment: It's for an assignment, and I fully agree that it makes no sense.  Do you have any idea how I can pass two struct-based linked lists into the operator, in that case?

Comment: Is the idea to concatinate to lists?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.  I don't want a whole answer, because I want to work the rest out on my own, but I am stuck on how to pass the two lists into the operator.  I updated the question with all my code.